# Failed to create Menus

Tags: windows-7, python, anaconda

[Hi I am facing below error"Failed to create menu" while installing Anaconda Menus attached screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a7pA.png) .Please help .
I have tried with all the options mentioned below:

Do not install on a PATH longer than 1024 characters.
Turn off anti-virus programs during install, then turn back on.
Uninstall all previous Python installations.
Clear all PATHs related to Python in sysdm.cpl file.
Delete any previously set up Java PATHs.
If JDK is installed, uninstall it.

Comment: Not sure if this is a solution to this exact problem, but don't install into a path with spaces

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. Try installing an older version (I installed a December 2018 version) from https://repo.continuum.io/archive/ -  it really worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, but only on a Win7 VM install without any updates at all.

The problem is that a _MEIxxxx folder [1] created by the installer is being deleted before it could be actually used [2].

My solution was to install the previous 2019.3 release instead, but maybe having installed some/all vc_redist* packages from MS could help too.

[1] https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works

[2] Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI23242\python36.dll'.